# Javascript - How to use reduce to create a new object with properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, reduce

I want to convert an array into an object and assign properties. I tried using the reduce method, but I am doing it by only returning one value in the array.

How can I get all values in the array and place them into my custom property in the new object?

**Initial array:**

```
["Cow Bell","Bass Drum","Maraca"]
```

**Reduce code:**

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

setFormData(() => {
  return props.incorrect_answers.reduce(
    (a, v) => ({ ...a, option: v }),
    {}
  );
});
```

**Output:**

```
{"option":"Maraca"} // Only outputs one value
```

**If I use this reduce code, it returns all values but with properties with the same name:**

```
setFormData(() => {
  return props.incorrect_answers.reduce(
    (a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v }),
    {}
  );
});
```

**Output:**

```
{"Cow Bell":"Cow Bell", "Bass Drum": "Bass Drum", "Maraca":"Maraca"} // Outputs all values but with the same property name
```

**Desired output I am looking for:**

```
{"option":"Cow Bell", "option":"Bass Drum", "option":"Maraca"}
```

Comment: A JavaScript object has unique keys, so you can't create one with repeated keys like your desired output. What are you intending to do with this object? That could help us suggest an answer.

Comment: ah makes sense, I would like to list the value of the object like 'Cow Bell' but I want to be able to call it using formData.option , or something similar

Comment: `props.incorrect_answers.map(option => ({ option }))` will produce an array of objects, each with an `option` property